# Putting a zipped object into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have object `zipped` instantiated as follows:

`zipped = zip(_artist_name, _artist_title, _xl, _l, _m, _s)`

Where the parameters are each an array of 30 strings. I have a dictionary `track_data` and under the key `recent_tracks` I have further key-value pairs that look like this:

```
track_data['recent_tracks'] = [
    {"artist": ?,
     "title": ?,
     "image_xl": ?,
     "image_l": ?,
     "image_m": ?,
     "image_s": ?}
]
```

I want `track_data['recent_tracks']` to contain 30 objects where each object contains 6 children. A bit like this:

```
object 1 - artist
           title
           xl
           l
           m
           s
object 2 - artist
           title
           xl
           l
           m
           s
```

The previous method I had was similar to the example above but it simply creates one object of 6 arrays with 30 objects. How do I iterate through the zipped item to assign the correct value to the corresponding pair in 30 separate objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add in keys and produce a dictionary for each of your `zipped` entries:

```
track_keys = ("artist", "title", "image_xl", "image_l", "image_m", "image_s")

zipped = zip(_artist_name, _artist_title, _xl, _l, _m, _s)
track_data['recent_tracks'] = [dict(zip(track_keys, values)) for values in zipped]
```

Demo:

```
>>> _artist_name = ['artist {}'.format(i + 1) for i in range(30)]
>>> _artist_title = ['title {}'.format(i + 1) for i in range(30)]
>>> _xl = ['xl image {}'.format(i + 1) for i in range(30)]
>>> _l = ['l image {}'.format(i + 1) for i in range(30)]
>>> _m = ['m image {}'.format(i + 1) for i in range(30)]
>>> _s = ['s image {}'.format(i + 1) for i in range(30)]
>>> 
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> track_keys = ("artist", "title", "image_xl", "image_l", "image_m", "image_s")
>>> zipped = zip(_artist_name, _artist_title, _xl, _l, _m, _s)
>>> pprint([dict(zip(track_keys, values)) for values in zipped])
[{'artist': 'artist 1',
  'image_l': 'l image 1',
  'image_m': 'm image 1',
  'image_s': 's image 1',
  'image_xl': 'xl image 1',
  'title': 'title 1'},
 {'artist': 'artist 2',
  'image_l': 'l image 2',
  'image_m': 'm image 2',
  'image_s': 's image 2',
  'image_xl': 'xl image 2',
  'title': 'title 2'},
 {'artist': 'artist 3',
  'image_l': 'l image 3',
  'image_m': 'm image 3',
  'image_s': 's image 3',
  'image_xl': 'xl image 3',
  'title': 'title 3'},
 {'artist': 'artist 4',
  'image_l': 'l image 4',
  'image_m': 'm image 4',
  'image_s': 's image 4',
  'image_xl': 'xl image 4',
  'title': 'title 4'},
 {'artist': 'artist 5',
  'image_l': 'l image 5',
  'image_m': 'm image 5',
  'image_s': 's image 5',
  'image_xl': 'xl image 5',
  'title': 'title 5'},
 {'artist': 'artist 6',
  'image_l': 'l image 6',
  'image_m': 'm image 6',
  'image_s': 's image 6',
  'image_xl': 'xl image 6',
  'title': 'title 6'},
 {'artist': 'artist 7',
  'image_l': 'l image 7',
  'image_m': 'm image 7',
  'image_s': 's image 7',
  'image_xl': 'xl image 7',
  'title': 'title 7'},
 {'artist': 'artist 8',
  'image_l': 'l image 8',
  'image_m': 'm image 8',
  'image_s': 's image 8',
  'image_xl': 'xl image 8',
  'title': 'title 8'},
 {'artist': 'artist 9',
  'image_l': 'l image 9',
  'image_m': 'm image 9',
  'image_s': 's image 9',
  'image_xl': 'xl image 9',
  'title': 'title 9'},
 {'artist': 'artist 10',
  'image_l': 'l image 10',
  'image_m': 'm image 10',
  'image_s': 's image 10',
  'image_xl': 'xl image 10',
  'title': 'title 10'},
 {'artist': 'artist 11',
  'image_l': 'l image 11',
  'image_m': 'm image 11',
  'image_s': 's image 11',
  'image_xl': 'xl image 11',
  'title': 'title 11'},
 {'artist': 'artist 12',
  'image_l': 'l image 12',
  'image_m': 'm image 12',
  'image_s': 's image 12',
  'image_xl': 'xl image 12',
  'title': 'title 12'},
 {'artist': 'artist 13',
  'image_l': 'l image 13',
  'image_m': 'm image 13',
  'image_s': 's image 13',
  'image_xl': 'xl image 13',
  'title': 'title 13'},
 {'artist': 'artist 14',
  'image_l': 'l image 14',
  'image_m': 'm image 14',
  'image_s': 's image 14',
  'image_xl': 'xl image 14',
  'title': 'title 14'},
 {'artist': 'artist 15',
  'image_l': 'l image 15',
  'image_m': 'm image 15',
  'image_s': 's image 15',
  'image_xl': 'xl image 15',
  'title': 'title 15'},
 {'artist': 'artist 16',
  'image_l': 'l image 16',
  'image_m': 'm image 16',
  'image_s': 's image 16',
  'image_xl': 'xl image 16',
  'title': 'title 16'},
 {'artist': 'artist 17',
  'image_l': 'l image 17',
  'image_m': 'm image 17',
  'image_s': 's image 17',
  'image_xl': 'xl image 17',
  'title': 'title 17'},
 {'artist': 'artist 18',
  'image_l': 'l image 18',
  'image_m': 'm image 18',
  'image_s': 's image 18',
  'image_xl': 'xl image 18',
  'title': 'title 18'},
 {'artist': 'artist 19',
  'image_l': 'l image 19',
  'image_m': 'm image 19',
  'image_s': 's image 19',
  'image_xl': 'xl image 19',
  'title': 'title 19'},
 {'artist': 'artist 20',
  'image_l': 'l image 20',
  'image_m': 'm image 20',
  'image_s': 's image 20',
  'image_xl': 'xl image 20',
  'title': 'title 20'},
 {'artist': 'artist 21',
  'image_l': 'l image 21',
  'image_m': 'm image 21',
  'image_s': 's image 21',
  'image_xl': 'xl image 21',
  'title': 'title 21'},
 {'artist': 'artist 22',
  'image_l': 'l image 22',
  'image_m': 'm image 22',
  'image_s': 's image 22',
  'image_xl': 'xl image 22',
  'title': 'title 22'},
 {'artist': 'artist 23',
  'image_l': 'l image 23',
  'image_m': 'm image 23',
  'image_s': 's image 23',
  'image_xl': 'xl image 23',
  'title': 'title 23'},
 {'artist': 'artist 24',
  'image_l': 'l image 24',
  'image_m': 'm image 24',
  'image_s': 's image 24',
  'image_xl': 'xl image 24',
  'title': 'title 24'},
 {'artist': 'artist 25',
  'image_l': 'l image 25',
  'image_m': 'm image 25',
  'image_s': 's image 25',
  'image_xl': 'xl image 25',
  'title': 'title 25'},
 {'artist': 'artist 26',
  'image_l': 'l image 26',
  'image_m': 'm image 26',
  'image_s': 's image 26',
  'image_xl': 'xl image 26',
  'title': 'title 26'},
 {'artist': 'artist 27',
  'image_l': 'l image 27',
  'image_m': 'm image 27',
  'image_s': 's image 27',
  'image_xl': 'xl image 27',
  'title': 'title 27'},
 {'artist': 'artist 28',
  'image_l': 'l image 28',
  'image_m': 'm image 28',
  'image_s': 's image 28',
  'image_xl': 'xl image 28',
  'title': 'title 28'},
 {'artist': 'artist 29',
  'image_l': 'l image 29',
  'image_m': 'm image 29',
  'image_s': 's image 29',
  'image_xl': 'xl image 29',
  'title': 'title 29'},
 {'artist': 'artist 30',
  'image_l': 'l image 30',
  'image_m': 'm image 30',
  'image_s': 's image 30',
  'image_xl': 'xl image 30',
  'title': 'title 30'}]
```